# Where does predefined TextViews reside in Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I am following an Udacity course ([How to use a Content Provider](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud258)). There is a piece of code which caught me in surprise.

Here is the class definition:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String[] COLUMNS_TO_BE_BOUND = new String[]{
            Words.WORD,
            Words.FREQUENCY,
    };

    private static final int[] LAYOUT_ITEMS_TO_FILL = new int[]{
            android.R.id.text1,
            android.R.id.text2,
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the TextView which will be populated with the Dictionary ContentProvider data.
        ListView dictListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_view);

        // Get the ContentResolver which will send a message to the ContentProvider
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

        // Get a Cursor containing all of the rows in the Words table
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                cursor,
                COLUMNS_TO_BE_BOUND,
                LAYOUT_ITEMS_TO_FILL,
                0);

        dictListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

and here is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dictionary_list_view">
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, this works perfectly, even though I did not declared any TextViews named text1 and text2.

When I right click on, say, text1 and say go to declaration, I go to the `[userprofile]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\values\ids.xml` and I see that id of TextViews are defined there.

My main question is, where are these TextViews (and bunch of other views in the ids.xml file) actually defined? And can I modify those?

My second question is, what is a reasonable approach to use a TextView which I defined myself? Should I define it in the activity_main.xml or should I put it in another layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are **platform resources**. The `android.R` package gives you that indication.

Android contains a number of standard resources, such as styles, themes, and layouts. To access these resource, you should qualify the resource reference with the `android` package name.

For you second question, yes you can define these layouts yourself in a separate layout file.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea where can I find the source file for those standard resources? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: For example, the one you are using is at `./frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/two_line_list_item.xml`